# command line arg not importing script

Tags: python, python-3.x

herro, noob programmer here facing quite the dilemma, trying to run a simple python script from terminal, it goes exactly as

## filename=test.py

```
from sys import argv
script, food, echo, tree=argv
print("the script is called:", script)
print("the first variable is called:", food)
print("the second variable is called:", echo)
print("blah blah third is:", tree)
```

(end of script)

in terminal

```
python3.7 test.py 1 2 3
```

when I hit enter in idle I just keep getting "valueError: not enough values to unpack)

this is driving me utter bananas, ANY help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Rollback to your original question with no modify as I may misunderstand your question. When you said `from terminal, it goes exactly as`, this means it runs ok? When you said `when I hit enter in idle`, you mean run in python idle is not ok?

Comment: terminal isn't passing arguements to my script being ran in shell, so far I've read if I write 'python3.7 test.py 1 2 3' in terminal, it should pass test.py(ARGV[0]), 1(ARGV[1]), so on, but its just not:/

Answer (score 1):

Well it runs in Python 2-3.7 but I had to make one change.

Change
`print("the script is called:", test.py)`
to
`print("the script is called:", script)`

I imagine that was likely just a typo.

Comment: that's the thing, I wrote it as "script" instead of "test.py", it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

it is because arguments and list unpacking is not matching 
try this

```
from sys import argv
# argv always take default argument as file path 
# at 0th position that is way 3+1
if len(argv) == 4:         
    script, food, echo, tree=argv
    print("the script is called:", script)
    print("the first variable is called:", food)
    print("the second variable is called:", echo)
    print("blah blah third is:", tree)
```

or use directly like this

```
print("the script is called:", argv[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
from sys import argv
script, food, echo, tree=argv
print("the script is called:", script)
print("the first variable is called:", food)
print("the second variable is called:", echo)
print("blah blah third is:", tree)

$ python3 ~/tmp/e test.py 1 2
the script is called: /home/bhepple/tmp/e
the first variable is called: test.py
the second variable is called: 1
blah blah third is: 2
```